# Prevent terminal prompt from printing on exec() call

Tags: shell, terminal, operating-system, exec, fork

SO,

There are many similar questions, however none that I have been able to use. My code snippet is as follows:

```
for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        exit(-1); //err
    } else if (pid == 0) {//kid
        stringstream ss;
        ss<<j;
        execlp("./sub","sub",ss.str().c_str(),NULL);
        exit(0);
    } else {
            /* parent */
    }
}
```

my executing code in sub(.cpp) is:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{

   cout<<argv[i]<<endl;
   exit(0);
}
```

my output is as such:

```
[terminal prompt '$'] 4
2
3
etc.
```

Is there a way I could prevent the prompt from displaying on the exec call? and why is it ONLY displaying on the first exec call, and not on every one?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the normal prompt of your shell, because the parent process terminates very quickly. It is not the output of the exec call. The forked processes print their output *after* the parent process has terminated.

You can use `waitpid()` in the parent process to "wait" until all forked process have terminated.

Comment: Thanks...that makes sense. My question still stands however; is there anyway to prevent it?

Comment: @DaxDurax: Why do you want to suppress it? It is normal behavior of a shell to print a prompt after a command has been executed.

Comment: @DaxDurax: I have added something to my answer, perhaps that is what you are looking for.